# Fastest way to get current user's OID in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, users, postgresql-9.3

I am thinking of storing the user's OID in the "owner" column of a table, so I don't have to do anything if they change their username.

I understand one can use pg_has_role() with OIDs, so that's good.

Is there a fast and easy way to get the current user's OID without just matching it against one of the system tables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fastest way I know of is a lookup in the system catalog view [`pg_roles`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'postgres';
```

Strictly speaking, it would be even slightly faster to use the underlying table [`pg_authid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-authid.html), but access to it is restricted to superusers for good reasons.

There is *no* [object identifier type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) like there is for tables or types, which would allow a simple cast like `'mytable'::regclass`.

OIDs are not stable across a dump / restore cycle. So, the **`OID` is no good** for the use case!

In some databases I have a separate `login` table with a serial primary key that I use for similar purposes. Maintained manually. And functions using it are prepared to occasionally not find a user in this table. A very basic and fast table:

```
CREATE TABLE users.login (
  login_id serial PRIMARY KEY  -- or even smallserial?
, username text NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

To create new users I use a PL/pgSQL function that creates the new user in the system and enters it into my table at the same time. And I use this `login_id` in *many places*. For instance I keep track of who made the last change to a row in most tables. I use this simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_login_id()
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT login_id FROM users.login
                 WHERE  username = session_user::text), 0::int);
$func$;
```

No foreign key constraints, to keep things fast and simple. Obviously, I don't need strict referential integrity.

Comment: Darn it. Thanks anyways. Can you describe your login table / system a little?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: I added the basic layout of my very simple design.